# use isolated scope variables in link method with directives - angularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-6">

                <div class="jumbotron" ng-controller="protocolCtrl as pctrl">


                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ng-click="pctrl.getUpdatedList()"
                        data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal">Modify Current Protocols</button>


                    <!--IN THIS MODAL YOU CAN ADD/CHANGE/DELETE DATA-->

                    <modal-directive list="pctrl" headers="['ID', 'Protocol']"></modal-directive>

                </div>

            </div>


            <div class="col-md-6">

                <div class="jumbotron" ng-controller="categoryCtrl as cctrl">


                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ng-click="cctrl.getUpdatedList()"
                        data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal">Modify Current Categories</button>


                    <!--IN THIS MODAL YOU CAN ADD/CHANGE/DELETE DATA-->

                    <modal-directive list="cctrl" headers="['ID', 'Category']"></modal-directive>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
```

In my `modal-directive`, I pass in `list` and `headers`.

My `modalDirective` looks like this:

```
angular.module('modalDirective', [])

.directive('modalDirective', function($compile){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: '/directives/modal-directive.html',
        scope: {
            list: '=',
            headers: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){

            if(attrs.list == 'pctrl'){
                element.find('.modal-body').prepend("protocol");
            } else {
                element.find('.modal-body').prepend("category");
            }
        }
    };
});
```

But no matter which of the buttons I click on in the `jumbtrons` it always appends `"protocol"`

What am I missing here?

**Edit**

```
here is the `modal-directive-html`

<div class="modal fade" id="modal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->

        <div class="modal-content">


            <!-- Modal header-->

            <div class="modal-header">
                <h3 class="modal-title">Protocols</h3>
            </div>

            <!-- Modal body-->

            <div class="modal-body">

<!--                this is where I append elements in the directives link function -->

                <table-directive list=list headers=headers></table-directive>

            </div>


            <!-- Modal footer-->

            <div class="modal-footer">

                <div class="pull-left">

                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"
                        data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you share a jsfiddle ?

Comment: Can you show me **modal-directive.html** file?

Comment: ^and whats in `categoryCtrl ` and `protocolCtrl `

Comment: @NLN the functionality of the controllers it not really relevant to my question i think, but I'll try and set up a fiddle to demostrate my problem

Answer (score 0):

I see from your isolated scope that you want the evaluated value from **list** not the literal one

to access these variables you need to use it like this ,,

```
if(scope.list == 'pctrl')
```

but if you used **attrs.list** it will compare against the literal value not the evaluated one